# Will Print Writer returned by HttpServletResponse use BufferedWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring Boot 2.2 application and I want to expose a Rest API for downloading CSV file.
I am writing my CSV data in a Writer returned by HttpServletResponse.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void messages(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        CSVWritter.write(writer, dataService.fetchAllUsers());
        writer.flush();
    }
```

As per HttpServletResponse API Java doc writer method will returns PrintWriter. But in Spring boot The reference is not of PrintWriter class instead if it was org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextPrintWriter[delegate=org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter@37ef8360]

I want that data should be written to browser in chunks i.e. it only flushes to browser when buffer is full. So The writer returned by response object is Buffered writer or is it using buffered writer internally?

Comment: `PrintWriter` is buffered itself, and it says so in the Javadoc. The object actually returned must be a `PrintWriter` or a derived class, so it must be buffered too.

Comment: I could not find any such information in javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: So why does it keep talking about flushing? Flushing what?

Comment: What I know is every writer implementation in java has small buffer. however Buffered Writer is a special buffered writer with keep in mind performance. i was asking about that.

Comment: @user207421 - `PrintWriter` is a decorator. The references to flushing in its docs are about invoking `flush()` on the delegate as part of each call to `print()` or `println()`.

Answer (score 0):

The [ServletResponse docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) aren't explicit, but the presence of the methods `flushBuffer()`, `getBufferSize()`, and `setBufferSize()` strongly imply that the output stream/writer is indeed buffered.

As a practical matter it has to be, to set `Content-Length` (or support chunked encoding, where content-length isn't known up-front).

NB: `PrintWriter` is a decorator; it is not internally buffered, but may decorate a writer that is buffered. The references to "flushing" in its docs relate to whether it explicitly calls `flush()` on the decorated `Writer` after every write.